# Progress Dialog not display well below and equal API Level 9 Android

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog

I have issue with ProgressDialog. My ProgressDialog is not displayed well in API level 9 or below. It looks like below:

[image]

Here What I am doing to display progress dialog.

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog( mContext );
dialog.setTitle( getResources().getString( R.string.checking_subscription ) );
dialog.setMessage( getResources().getString( R.string.please_wait ) );
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside( false );
dialog.setProgressStyle( ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER );
dialog.show();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you used theme for dialogs? Check your theme. If yes then try once after commenting theme related to dialog.

Comment: no you can see the code thats it what i write to display progress dialog

Comment: I am asking about style... check your style.xml file into values dir.

Comment: wait i am checking actually it is maintaince project. so i have to check it. :)

Comment: great @PankajKumar. thats the issue thanks a lot.

Comment: please add your answer . so other can get help if they face the same

Comment: Added the answer. You can check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title of the `ProgressDialog` as you added into picture is not as default theme of OS. It seems that you are using custom view for Dialog title.

So make sure that if you are not using custom theme for Dialog. Check at ***`APP_DIR/res/values/styles.xml`***. Theme for Dialog will be applied for all Views of Dialog family.

So you can remove that theme if you don't want.

Comment: yes in style.xml one property for background color causing the issue. <item name="android:background">#fff</item>